# Envelope schema without payload : timeout

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a request-response port a receive location holding WCF-BasicHttp adapter. The receive location has a custom pipeline attached where I have put an XML Disassembler in it hold an envelope schema. That envelope schema is a request holding some request elements and a payload any element. The XML disassembler extracts this payload and publishes it onto the MessageBox.

Now my question:

When I put a request in without a payload content I get a timeout (from WCF, defaulted 1 minute). Also I get a timeout when I put in a non-xml content (like 'aaaaa').

What happens in Biztalk in both scenario's (I don't get the point of why timeouts occur in both scenario's).... ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly provide more info please?

e.g. 
Did you publish an orchestration which receives the request and creates the response?
Are you using the Isolated hosts, or have you created a receive location directly on a BizTalk host process?

I'm not sure if this is applicable, but if you publish an orchestration as a WCF service(without taking any enveloping or pipeline processing into account), once the receive location is created, *any* message can be sent to the location provided that it meets some envelope criteria (the default is the SOAP message envelope, but you can override this in the receive location message settings). One or more orchestrations can then receive this message, and any message(s) sent back to the response of the port will be sent back to the caller.

So if you publish empty or non-conformant data to the receive location, the orchestration won't receive the message at all and it is likely to be suspended instead.
As a result, your WCF client won't receive a reply, and hence will eventually timeout.

Comment: Yes there is one orchestration which creates a generic response message (this notify means that the payload has been received in Biztalk/Messagebox). There is one isolated host, one receive location bound to this host. I used the Biztalk WCF Service Publishing wizard to publish this orchestration as WCF request-response port (during publishing I changed the message variable to the specific request schema, after publishing I changed it to XmlDocument).